# Reproducir vídeo de YouTube al pulsar un botón en Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

Tengo una aplicación para reproducir vídeos de Youtube aleatoriamente usando la API de YouTube, para obtener una id de video aleatoria y reproducir el vídeo tengo un botón llamado siguienteVideo, pero al pulsar no deja invocar los métodos de youtubePlayer:

```
public void siguienteVideo(View v){
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
    youTubePlayer.play();
}
```

Ni utilizar métodos públicos de la api como:

```
public void cueVideo (String videoId){
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
    youTubePlayer.play();
}

public void siguienteVideo(View v){
    cueVideo(idVideoFinal);
}
```

Me salta esta excepción:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

Inicializacion:

```
//Método para comprobar si fue bien
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    //Si fue bien entonces carga y reproduce el video
    if(!b){
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

        //Carga y reproduce directamente el video
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo("DRS_PpOrUZ4");
        youTubePlayer.play();

    }
}

//Método para comprobar si algo fue mal
@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    //Si existió algún error al inicializar muestra un dialog con el error
    if(youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){
        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, 1).show();
    }
    //Si YT no sabe cual es el error enviará este mensaje
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al inializar YouTube "+youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

El youtubePlayer que no me funciona es el del botón de siguienteVideo(View v)

**SOLUCIÓN**

He encontrado una solución al problema:

Como variable global tengo una variable de tipo YoutubePlayer

```
private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer1;
```

Y a la hora de inicializar:

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    //Si fue bien entonces carga y reproduce el video
    if(!b){
        youTubePlayer1=youTubePlayer;
        youTubePlayer1.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

        //Carga y reproduce directamente el video
        youTubePlayer1.loadVideo("DRS_PpOrUZ4");
        youTubePlayer1.play();

    }
}
```

Y así ya se puede usar en cualquier sitio:

```
public void siguienteVideo(View v){
    youTubePlayer1.loadVideo("ZsUMwahBvh8");
    youTubePlayer1.play();
}
```

Comment: Agrega el mensaje en el LogCat que indica el error, es importante, donde dice "Caused by", este problema se produce porque el método llamado tiene un problema. Agrega esta información para actualizar mi respuesta @Beardman

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.loadVideo(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Agregue el problema y que debes realizar para corregirlo que es inicializar youTubePlayer @Beardman , si no puedes corregirlo, te sugiero agregues toda tu clase para que te apoyemos.

Comment: Lo acabo de editar

Comment: No necesitas crear una variable global tipo YoutubePlayer y realizar esto : youTubePlayer1=youTubePlayer; Simplemente toma el valor de youTubePlayer que entrega onInitializationSuccess() , revisa mi repuesta. @Beardman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si llamas los métodos desde tu layout mediante `android:onClick` debes definir el nombre del método:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    ...
    ...
    android:onClick="playVideo" />
```

y en código definir el método, este debe recibir como parámetro una vista `(View v)`:

```
public void playVideo(View v){
    ...
    ...
}
```

Con respecto al problema :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick

**esto sucede si llamas correctamente tu método pero este método tiene un error al ejecutarse.** En esta caso el error es:

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.loadVideo(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference

y esta sucediendo porque la variable `youTubePlayer` no esta inicializada en esta linea de código:

```
youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
```

---

#### YouTube API de Android

Para usar esta API, la inicialización puede realizarse en `onCreate()` y en [onInitializationSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener#onInitializationSuccess(com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider,%20com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer,%20boolean)) aseguras que se inicio correctamente, y es donde puedes reproducir tu video.

Es importante saber que tu clase debe extender de [YouTubeBaseActivity](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeBaseActivity):

```
public class MainActivity  extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
```

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    private String ID_VIDEO = "_7I1sjCdB_I";
    private String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = ".................";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(ID_VIDEO);
        youTubePlayer.play();

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Como inicializo la variable youtubePlayer ?

Comment: @Beardman agrega el código de tu clase para ayudarte

Comment: Lo acabo de editar

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta @Beardman